# php - Explode string and insert into multiple rows with foreach is too slow

Tags: php, mysql

I want to explode a string with a space, check whether the word already exists. If not, insert each piece into multiple rows in mysql db. I've tried this before...

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    include("connect.php");
    $counter = 0;
    $counters = 0;
    $string = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['words']);
    $arr = explode(" ",$string);
    foreach($arr as $str) {
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM unicode WHERE word = '$str'") or die (mysql_error());
        if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0) {
            $sqli = mysql_query("INSERT INTO unicode (word) VALUES ('$str')") or die (mysql_error());
            $counters++;
        } elseif (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) { 
            $counter++;
        }
    }
    header("Location: ../addspellwords?success=457394056369&entered=$counters&duplicates=$counter");
}
?>
```

This is too too too much slow....

Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can the `word` column in table `unicode` be unique?

Comment: You have an extra `}` at the end. Is it intended?

Comment: this is end of the server request @PraveenKumar

Comment: Okay, I got it now. Sorry, my mistake! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what's passed you can go `SELECT` the words that currently exist, then leave those out on the `INSERT`. Another option may be `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY` if your `word` column is a key (which I hope based on your code).  Try the following:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    include("connect.php");
    $counter = 0;
    $counters = 0;
    $string = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['words']);
    $arr = explode(" ",$string);

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT `word` FROM unicode WHERE word IN ('".implode("', '", $arr) . ")") or die (mysql_error());
    $dupes = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) {
        $dupes[] = $r['word'];
    }
    $newwords = array_diff($arr, $dupes);
    if(count($newwords)) {
        $sqli = mysql_query("INSERT INTO unicode (word) VALUES ('" . implode("'),('", $newwords) . "')") or die (mysql_error());
    }
    header("Location: ../addspellwords?success=457394056369&entered=".count($newwords)."&duplicates=".count($dupes));
}
?>
```

Comment: You could even improve it slightly by using [array_unique()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) on the $arr array